# How do you pair an iPhone with Vista over Bluetooth?

Tags: windows-vista, iphone, bluetooth

I turned on Bluetooth in both the laptop and my iPhone.
The device shows up and I get the pair code dialog on the laptop.
Once it is paired, Vista shows the "Found new hardware..." dialog. 
At this point, I'm lost.  I was hoping for an "it just works" situation, but since that didn't happen, what driver to I attach to the phone to make it go?

I am partly trying this in response to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1208/has-anyone-had-any-success-with-tethering-the-iphone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the link provided by [ianix](https://superuser.com/questions/5812/how-do-you-pair-an-iphone-with-vista-over-bluetooth/5905#5905) the trick seems to be two things.  Once the bluetooth is turned on on both systems and paired and Internet tethering is enabled on the iPhone, there are two tricks.  First is to ignore the driver request and make sure that once the application is paired, you ensure that the Wireless iAP checkbox is checked on your device.  Second, just right click on the bluetooth icon in the task bar and select "Join a Personal Area Network".

Really, I just needed know that ignoring the driver request is the right way to go there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have iTunes installed? I had to install it on my windows machine to get tethering to work. I'm sure it's installing drivers the iphone needs.

Comment: You actually don't need to install iTunes if you are just using the bluetooth tethering.  USB tethering requires the AppleMobileDeviceSupport.msi to be installed.  That comes with iTunes.